# What's the difference between a section and a dependent function?

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

I'm reading [Introduction to Homotopy Type Theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2212.11082.pdf) by Egbert Rĳke and get confused by the notions of a section and a dependent function.

A section is defined as:

> **Definition 1.2.2** Consider a type family $$ over $$ in context $Γ$. A **section** of
> the family $$ over $$ in context $Γ$ is an element of type $()$ in context $Γ,  : $,
> i.e., in the judgment
> $$Γ,  :  \vdash () : ()$$
> we say that $$ is a section of the family $$ over $$ in context $Γ$. Alternatively, we
> say that $()$ is an element of type $()$ indexed by $ : $ in context $Γ$.

Dependent functions are defined as:

> Consider a section $$ of a family $$ over $$ in context $Γ$, i.e., consider
> $$Γ,  :  \vdash () : ()$$
> From one point of view, such a section $$ is an operation or assignment $ \mapsto ()$, or a program, that takes as input $ : $ and produces a term $() : ()$. From a more mathematical point of view we see  as a choice of an element of each
> $()$. In other words, we may see $$ as a function that takes $ : $ to $() : ()$. Note that the type $()$ of the output may depend on $ : $. The assignment $ \mapsto ()$ is in this sense a dependent function.

I don't see any difference between them. Why there is a need to define dependent function when there is a section? And how they relate to each other?

Comment: I don't see a definition of "dependent functions" here.  Your second paragraph just asserts that sections are an example of such, but there is no definition given.

Comment: @lulu that citation is from page 11. It continues as follows: "The type of all such dependent functions is called the dependent function type, and we will write $\prod_{x:A} B(x)$ for the type of dependent functions." If a dependent function is a section which in turn is a term of a family of types then why there is a need to specify separately dependent function type?

Comment: Well, I still don't see a definition.  It looks like a vague expression just to stress the dependency.  If they intended something more, they ought to have defined it.

Comment: Not confident enough in this to post as an answer -- but maybe, sections and dependent functions are essentially the same thing, but "sections" would invoke more of the geometric picture of the object, whereas "dependent function" would invoke more of the algebraic or computation picture.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that by, "dependent function," the author has in mind some particular characterization in, say, set theory. That is, it is some refinement or variant of the notion of "function" there. In particular, they seem to distinguish that notion from (appropriately behaving) programs.

So, in that sense, a "section" in type theory needn't be a, "dependent function," because we might not be thinking of type theory decoding into some set theoretic semantics in which that notion of function lives. In general you can interpret type theory in a wide range of categories, and the "sections" there (which have a different-looking definition, but nevertheless are used to model the type theory notion) needn't be functions at all, strictly speaking.

However, if by, "dependent function," you mean the objects in the type theory that seem like functions that can be applied to values $x : A$ to yield values of $B(x)$, then clearly those are what the book is calling "sections," and they are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a bunch of sets $B(x)$ indexed by another set $x\in A$, then you can for example imagine that a dependent function is a function $f:A\to \bigcup_{x\in A}B(x)$ such that each $f(a)$ is an element of $B(a)$. Alternatively, you can do the following. You take the sets $B(x)$ and form their disjoint union $\bigsqcup_{x\in A}B(x)$ and define a projection map $\pi_B:\bigsqcup_{x\in A} B(x)\to A$ which collapses each fiber $B(x)$ to the point $x$. A dependent function in the first sense is then the same data as a section of $\pi_B$. The second perspective is the one more appropriate for type theory, because type theory is meant to be interpreted in categories in which "elements of an object" do not literally exist.

The interpretation of $x:A\vdash B(x):Type$ in a category $\mathcal S$ is a morphism $\pi_B:A.B\to A$ called the display map of $B$. The interpretation of a dependent term $x:A\vdash b(x):B(x)$ is a section of the display map $\pi_B$. You should imagine that this section picks one element in the fiber $B(x)$ for each element $x$ of $A$, although that can not literally be true in an abitrary category $\mathcal S$. In that sense $b(x)$ contains the same data as a function whose target set depends on the input.

So maybe those paragraphs are meant to make you aware of an important idea in dependent type theory, namely to view an indexed family $(B(x))_{x\in A}$ of sets as a map into $A$ whose fibers are the $B(x)$.